# Eclipse Indigo - Unable to Install PHP Plugin

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin

I'm getting the error message `Error occurred while collecting items to be installed` while installing a PHP plugin in Eclipse Indigo. Can anyone provide me the exact link to install the PHP plugin in Eclipse Indigo SR2?

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse and go to Help-> Software Updates-> Find and Install Select "Search for new features to install" and click "Next" Create a New Remote Site with the following details:

Name: PDT

URL: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release

Check the PDT box and click "Next" to start the installation

Hope it helps